# Receiving a status of 404 when implementing GET request - MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I'm trying to display a particular group detail page from the group's list. I have managed to display all the group lists from the backend, but when it comes to displaying each group detail page, I'm receiving a status of 404. I don't understand what the issue is, why it can't find that group on that particular id.

On Backend, I made a getGroup controller:

```
export const getGroup = async (req, res) => {
    // Route parameters are named URL segments that are used to capture the values specified at their position in the URL.
    // Deconstructing it so that we can use it. It's like unpacking it.
    const { id } = req.params

    try {
        // finding a group by it's Id
        const group = await Group.findById(id)
        // Send it in response
        res.status(200).json(group)

    } catch (error) {
        // In case it didn't work out
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message })
    }
}
```

Then Routes:

```
router.get('/:id', getGroup)
```

Main Route:

```
app.use('/groups', groupRoutes)
```

On Front End, I'm using Axios to create an API.

```
export const fetchGroup = (id) => API.get(`/groups/${id}`)
```

Using Redux for state management, so here is my action creator for a particular group.

```
// Will get a particular group
export const getGroup = (id) => async (dispatch) => {

    try {
        // Over here we are fetching all the data from api and dispatching it.
        const { data } = await api.fetchGroup(id)

        dispatch({type: FETCH_GROUP, payload: data})

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}
```

Reducer for fetching a group:

```
// Reducers take state and an action as arguments and return a new state in result.
const groups = ( state = { groups: [] }, action ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                groups: action.payload 
            }
        case FETCH_GROUP:
            // set to group because we are getting a single group
            return { ...state, group: action.payload } 
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default groups
```

My GroupPage.js, where I'm dispatching my functions.

```
const GroupPage = () => {

    const { group } = useSelector((state) => state.groups)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { id } = useParams()
    
    useEffect(()=> {
        dispatch(getGroup(id))
    }, [id])
    
    //if(!group) return null

    return (
        isLoading ? <div style={{width: 50, height: 50 }}>
        <CircularProgressbar value={66} text={66} />
    </div> : (
        <div>
           <Container>
                <Top>
                    <div>
                        <h1>{group.groupName}</h1>
                        <p>{group.location}</p>
                        <p>{group.members}</p>
                    </div>
                </Top>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
  )
}

export default GroupPage
```

From the above code, if I check for a group:
`if(!group) return null`
Then I'm getting the error
`typeError: Cannot read property 'groupName' of undefined`

Not sure what the problem is. I have also tried the data fetching with the loading state, but that didn't resolve the issue either.
Please, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In your redux state you have declared ```groups``` as an array , try changing it an object and try the condition you have commented if (!group)

Comment: Try debugging the routes,see what exactly have you mentioned the routes in backend

Comment: @jarivak I tried changing it to object and remove the comments from the condition, but still, it comes back with no data. For getGroup I have mentioned `router.get('/:id', getGroup)`

Comment: Your backend is running on which port?

Comment: `res.status(404)` is this the one causing this issue? 
Try to add a logger under the catch block.